# Error in Unit Testing Angular code with Karma and Jasmine - Executed 0 of 0 ERROR

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to unit test my Angular code with Karma and Jasmine. After navigating to the project folder I have executed the following commands in the mentioned sequence:

**npm install --save-dev jasmine** (for installing Jasmine)
**npm install --save-dev karma** (for installing Karma)
**npm install --save-dev karma-jasmine** (for installing Karma dependencies)
**karma init**

After that when I try to run **karma start**, I am getting the below error which says **Executed 0 of 0 ERROR** and nothing specific.

Any clue behind why I am getting this? I have also added my karma.config.js and spec-bundle.js file contents below.

[image]

My karma.config.js file:

```js
   // Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    basePath: '.',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
        '../../wwwroot/dist/vendor.js',
        './boot-tests.ts'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
        './boot-tests.ts': ['webpack']
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    //browsers: ['PhantomJS'], // use headless browswer
    browsers: [
        'Chrome',
        'Chrome_with_debugging'
    ],

    customLaunchers: {

        Chrome_with_debugging: {
            base: 'Chrome',
            //chromeDataDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '.chrome'),
            flags: ['--remote-debugging-port=9333'],
            displayName: 'Chrome with remote debugging'
        }
    },
    mime: { 'application/javascript': ['ts', 'tsx'] },
    // Which plugins to enable defaults to karma-*

    singleRun: false,
    webpack: require('../../webpack.config.js')().filter(config => config.target !== 'node'), // Test against client bundle, because tests run in a browser
    webpackMiddleware: { stats: 'errors-only' }
});
};
```

My spec-bundle.js file:

```js
/*
 * When testing with webpack and ES6, we have to do some extra
 * things to get testing to work right. Because we are gonna write tests
 * in ES6 too, we have to compile those as well. That's handled in
 * karma.conf.js with the karma-webpack plugin. This is the entry
 * file for webpack test. Just like webpack will create a bundle.js
 * file for our client, when we run test, it will compile and bundle them
 * all here! Crazy huh. So we need to do some setup
 */
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

require('core-js/es6');
require('core-js/es7/reflect');

require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
require('zone.js/dist/proxy'); // since zone.js 0.6.15
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');
require('zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch'); // put here since zone.js 0.6.14
require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');

// RxJS
require('rxjs/Rx');

var testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
var browser = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');

testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
  browser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  browser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

/*
 * Ok, this is kinda crazy. We can use the context method on
 * require that webpack created in order to tell webpack
 * what files we actually want to require or import.
 * Below, context will be a function/object with file names as keys.
 * Using that regex we are saying look in ../Client then find
 * any file that ends with spec.ts and get its path. By passing in true
 * we say do this recursively
 */
var testContext = require.context('../ClientApp', true, /\.spec\.ts/);

/*
 * get all the files, for each file, call the context function
 * that will require the file and load it up here. Context will
 * loop and require those spec files here
 */
function requireAll(requireContext) {
  return requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
}

// requires and returns all modules that match
var modules = requireAll(testContext);
```

Comment: can you also post your karma config file?

Comment: @HrishikeshKale posted, please check.

Comment: you haven't included plugins in conf file like this "plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine')]"  you can add as many requires as your want. Share your  spec-bundle file. Your karma is not including test files thatz y 0 of 0.

Comment: looking to your console, you are using chrome browser try adding mime: {
  'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']
} in your karma.conf.js also make autoWatch: true, to check changes in your file

Comment: also please check the files array have correct file path.

Comment: I have added my spec-bundle.js file to this post @Akanksha. Please check.

Comment: @HrishikeshKale, changes made, but still no luck.Edited code is attached above,

Comment: You will get this error if there are no tests to run.  Check that you have tests defined, and that the boot-tests.ts file is correctly referencing them.